# Calculate unique dates in multiple date ranges

Tags: excel, date

Here's one that does my head in, so perhaps somebody can help prevent a migraine? :-)

I have a sheet in which one column contains a start date and another one an end date. I have a third column that calculates how many days there are between the start date and end date (with 1 added to it to get the correct count, because a start date that is equal to an end date needs to be counted as one, not zero).

However, between different rows the periods can overlap, so I can have (warning: British date format dd/MM/yy):

```
Start       End         Days
22/01/17    26/01/17    5
24/01/17    24/01/17    1
```

Because the 24th is already counted in the first row, I don't want to count it again when I get the grand total of all days. How can I achieve this??

Thanks in advance!

Lucien.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short - I cannot think of a good and clear way to do it just with Excel. 
However, with VBA there is a good way:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim lngCounter          As Long
    Dim dtStartDate         As Date
    Dim dtEndDate           As Date
    Dim collDates           As New Collection

    dtStartDate = CDate("22.01.2015")
    dtEndDate = CDate("25.01.2015")

    For lngCounter = dtStartDate To dtEndDate
        If Not Contains(collDates, lngCounter) Then
            collDates.Add lngCounter
        End If
    Next lngCounter

    dtStartDate = CDate("23.01.2015")
    dtEndDate = CDate("28.01.2015")

    For lngCounter = dtStartDate To dtEndDate
        If Not Contains(collDates, lngCounter) Then
            collDates.Add lngCounter
        End If
    Next lngCounter

    For lngCounter = 1 To collDates.Count
        Debug.Print CDate(collDates(lngCounter))
    Next lngCounter

End Sub

Public Function Contains(ByRef col As Collection, ByRef key As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim lngCounter As Long

    Contains = True

    For lngCounter = 1 To col.Count
        If col(lngCounter) = key Then Exit Function
    Next lngCounter

    Contains = False

End Function
```

You give twice `dtStartDate` and `dtEndDate` and you save the dates in between as numbers in a collection `collDates`, if they are not there already.

Comment: Thanks. This is similar to the solution someone suggested elsewhere and I started using:
`Option Explicit
Function UniqueDayCount(rStart As Range, rEnd As Range) As Long
    Dim col As Collection
    Dim vStart As Variant, vEnd As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    
    vStart = rStart
    vEnd = rEnd
    On Error Resume Next
    Set col = New Collection
    For I = 1 To UBound(vStart)
        For J = vStart(I, 1) To vEnd(I, 1)
            col.Add Item:=J, Key:=CStr(J)
        Next J
    Next I
    On Error GoTo 0
    UniqueDayCount = col.Count
End Function
`

Comment: Can you put the code in pastebin.com? And give a link? :)

Answer (score 1):

If you require both total days per line and per column then you could always have a separate column to add the unique days (this assumes that the start dates are in date order)
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the order is not guaranteed and there are both overlaps and gaps between date periods.

Answer (score 0):

If you have start date in column A, end date in column B and datedifference in column C, you can count without doubles with the following two array formulas in column D and E (this solution doesn't require an ascending order).

Please note that this these are array formulas and that you have to confirm them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of only pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd>-key.

Column D:

```
=COUNT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2-1+(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&C2))),E1)),"",A2-1+(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&C2)))))
```

Column E:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2-1+(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&C2))),E1)),"",A2-1+(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&C2)))),E1)
```

You need Excel 2016 so you can achieve the desired result because the textjoin()-function is a new one.

[image: count distinct textjoin]

how it works:
the array formula splits all the dates between start-date and end-date into rows and searches them as an integer in the concatenated string, if there is a match, the date will be "blanked" out and the other distinct results will be concatenated with the previous distinct results saved in a growing string.

Comment: Very clever. I had been thinking along the same lines for a while, but couldn't quite get it to work. Can this be done 'invisibly'? And would the performance not be slower than a UDF/macro, given that it is cumulative?

Answer (score 0):

The other approach to making a list of the used dates is to use a 'sieve' method by generating an array over the entire range of dates (from earliest start date to latest end date) then filling in the ones that are used

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN(COUNTIFS(A2:A10,"<="&ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(A2:A10)&":"&MAX(B2:B10))),B2:B10,">="&ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(A2:A10)&":"&MAX(B2:B10))))))
```

[image]

(The numbers in column D have just been put in manually as a check and aren't used in the calculation).

This shows what the array looks like

[image]

Comment: Where does it store that array, Tom?

Comment: The array is just temporary, it isn't stored anywhere. If you took the middle of the formula =SIGN(COUNTIFS(A2:A10,"<="&ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(A2:A10)&":"&MAX(B2:B10))),
B2:B10,">="&ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(A2:A10)&":"&MAX(B2:B10))))) and entered it as an array formula into a range of cells, you would see the array mapped out as a series of 0's (for dates that aren't used) and ones (for dates that are used).